# Local Backup from Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.3, amazon-rds, pg-dump

I have a PostgreSQL database on an Amazon RDS instance.

I want to have a local dump of this instance.

So far, I've tried with this:

```
PGPASSWORD="Password" pg_dump -h mydb.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432
```

But it keeps throwing an error, saying that the server refuse the connection, and check if the server is actually running on port `5432`, which is actually doing.

All my credentials and DB path/codes are correct.

Comment: Can you connect using `psql` using those parameters?

Comment: Nope :( I don't get it, these are correct, maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: psql -U user_ -h xxxxx.amazoncode.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com db - Nothing...

Comment: Check those: Is your host in the samce VPC as the RDS? Is your RDS configured to be publicly accessible? Does the xxx.us-east....com resolve in a private or public IP from your VM? If it's private, are they on the same subnet/VPC? If all the above are correct check also RDS firewall (security group) settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must be running in a Security Group firewall problem.

- Go to your RDS Dashboard, select Instances and open the instance you want to connect to.
- Look for a line like this : `Security Groups rds-launch-wizard (sg-3e9axxx) ( active )`. You should be able to click on `rds-launch-wizard (sg-3e9axxx)` which leads you to the EC2 Dashboard in the `Security Groups` panel.
- Select your security group and open the `Inbound` Tab in the lower panel.
- Click on `Edit` and `Add Rule`. Don't forget to set the `Port Range` to 5432 and select `My IP` in the source.
- Click on `Save`.
- You should be able to connect to your RDS Instance from your local IP.